# Identity morphism is unique

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification

I started reading Ravi Vakil's notes *The Rising Sea - Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*. On p. 26 he writes: 'If you wish, you may check that “identity morphisms are unique”'.

So I tried doing this and wonder whether I am correct.

Let $\text{id}_{A} : A \rightarrow A$ and $\bar{\text{id}}_{A} : A \rightarrow A$ be two identity morphisms. Then, $\text{id}_{A} \circ \bar{\text{id}}_{A} = \bar{\text{id}}_{A}$ and $\text{id}_{A} \circ \bar{\text{id}}_{A} = \text{id}_{A}$; since we know that if we left or right compose a morphism with the identity, we get the same morphism. Hence, $\text{id}_{A} = \bar{\text{id}}_{A}$.

Comment: That's certainly the right idea and your proof is correct. This proof tends to get written as $\overline{id}_A = id_A \circ \overline{id}_A = id_A$ to really emphasize that they are the same thing.